# PyCharm doesn't recognize Buildout dependencies

Tags: pycharm, buildout

I have a fairly simple project with Buildout and Django and have imported it into PyCharm. However, even after enabling Buildout support in the project settings, PyCharm complains that it can't find Django. The project, when built from Buildout, works just fine, but PyCharm is not seeing it as a Buildout project properly.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: 9 years later and PyCharm now doesn't support Buildout again ️

Answer (score 4):

This probably is a problem because you do not have your interpreters set out straight. Check to see that you have all the dependencies installed. This picture can demonstrate:

[image]