# PyCharm and buildout with another package under development

Tags: python, dependencies, pycharm, buildout

I have a specialized buildout package, say, my.buildout, and under src there is MyProject package (which does not have buidlout.cfg by itself, but of course do have setup.py). These are the relevant lines in buildout.cfg in addition to sources:

```
develop = src/MyProject
auto-checkout = MyProject
```

When I run bootstrap and bin/buildout, src/MyProject is automatically checked out, and bin/pserve script (and many other scripts under bin) contains paths to all dependencies.

The python interpreter is coming from one of the virtual envs I have. Note, that dependencies are installed by buildout under eggs, not in the virtual env.

I want PyCharm to understand whereabouts of both MyProject and the eggs, that is, everything, which is normally available when the project is running.

Tried to add my.buildout as a project, added correct python interpreter. When I go into MyProject, dependencies are underlined in red.

Also tried to add MyProject as a project, with the same result.

I am aware of this answer:

[PyCharm doesn't recognize Buildout dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324744/pycharm-doesnt-recognize-buildout-dependencies)

but I have set up interpreter to the one in the #! of the bin/pserve, and "bin/py" script, which is used as a wrapper, naturally can't be added as an interpreter.

Is it possible to have my.buildout and MyProject as they are, or is buildout support of PyCharm intended for some different buildout structure / development workflow?
(and sometimes there are many projects under development is src, I've simplified)

I am very new to PyCharm (trying it out), so may be missing something obvious.

**Update:** Of course, I've enabled Buildout support in the settings, and used the full path to my.buildout/bin/buildout script.

Just to make it clearer. In the bin/pserve script (generated by buildout), which is used to run the app, a lot of paths are inserted into sys.path. PyCharm just does not read those. The question is how to make it aware of those paths.

**Update 2**: And even more: when I give bin/py as a buidlout script in the Settings, the project panel faithfully lists "Buildout Eggs" (from sys.path?), but still shows "Package requirements .... " Install / Ignore suggestion.

Comment: I don't know anything about pyCharm but https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.omelette/ my help you. it symlink everything you need together.

Comment: Thanks, however, I am aware of omelette (grep -r also works fine in the eggs dir). The question is how PyCharm can find modules in eggs from MyProject source files. I am speaking about the normal IDE's function (signature lookup, etc).

Comment: Did you try Preferences -> Build, Execution, and Deployment -> Buildout Support and enable it for the project?

Comment: Of course. That is how I got an idea that PyCharm supports buildout.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after adding .../bin/py (instead of bin/buildout, which does not contain but two paths) as a "Use paths from script" in the Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Buildout Support I am getting lookups right!

(Even though PyCharm still suggests to install requirements)

Comment: Great! I have a project with pyramid. I got the error `Cannot Save Settings: Failed to extract paths from 'buildout'`. I my case i had to choose `bin/pserve` instead of `bin/buildout`. Tooked me a while ... ;)